# Realloc in a 2d array of pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to create a dynamic array of simple linked lists. The MAX_SIZE is 5. I would like to insert
a new node, for example the character 'c', at (**link[5]**). For every new character, i would like to allocate a new entry at the bottom of the array.

When i execute my code, I get this output above. I think there is a problem with realloc

```
[0] a b NULL
[1] c NULL
[2] f e d NULL
[3] NULL
[4] NULL
```

but the expected output is below:

```
[0] a b NULL
[1] c NULL
[2] f e d NULL
[3] NULL
[4] NULL
[5] c
```

My code is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;


int push_front( Node **head, char data )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void output( Node **head )
{
    for( Node *current =*head; current != NULL && current->data != -1 ; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%c ", current->data );
    }
    printf( "%s", "NULL" );
}

void display( Node **set, int n )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("[%d] ", i);
        output(&(set[i]));
        printf("\n");
    }

}

#define N   5

int main(void)
{
    //Node * link[N] = { 0 };
    Node **link;
    link = calloc(N , sizeof (Node*));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        link[i] = calloc(N , sizeof (Node));
        link[i]->data = -1;
    }


    push_front( &link[0], 'b' );
    push_front( &link[0], 'a' );
    push_front( &link[1], 'c' );
    push_front( &link[2], 'd' );
    push_front( &link[2], 'e' );
    push_front( &link[2], 'f' );


    link = (Node **) realloc(link, (N + 1) * sizeof(Node*));
    for(int i = 0; i < N + 1; i++){
        link[i] = (Node *)realloc(link[i],(N + 1) * sizeof(Node));
    }

    push_front( &link[5], 'c' );

    display(link, N);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is doing some serious mistake while allocating memory to list and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67448840/1366871) is not pointing out those mistakes. Hence, I am posting this answer.

> *I am trying to create a dynamic array of simple linked lists....*

The way you are allocating memory, initially, you are creating array of array's of `Node` type objects.

From [calloc()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc): *[emphasis added]*

> > ```
> >  void* calloc( size_t num, size_t size );
> > ```
>
> Allocates memory for **an array of *num* objects of *size*** and initializes all bytes in the allocated storage to zero.

So, this loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        link[i] = calloc(N , sizeof (Node));
        link[i]->data = -1;
    }
```

will end up allocating memory for an array of `N` objects of size of `Node` type to `link[i]` pointer, where value of `i` lies in `[0, 5)`.

The in-memory view would be something like this:

```
(read `n` as `next` pointer 
 and `:` is separator between `data` and `next` member of a node)

          ----    ----------------------
 link[0]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|     <---- array of Node type objects
          |  |    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----    ----------------------
 link[1]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|     <---- array of Node type objects
          |  |    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----    ----------------------
 link[2]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|     <---- array of Node type objects
          |  |    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----    ----------------------
 link[3]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|     <---- array of Node type objects
          |  |    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----    ----------------------
 link[4]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|     <---- array of Node type objects
          |  |    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----
```

After calling `push_front()` on `link` array elements, the in-memory view would be something like this:

```
(read `n` as `next` pointer 
 and `:` is separator between `data` and `next` member of a node) 

          ----    -----    -----    ----------------------
 link[0]  |  | -> |a:n| -> |b:n| -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|
          |  |    -----    -----    ----------------------
          |  |        
          ----    -----    ----------------------
 link[1]  |  | -> |c:n| -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|
          |  |    -----    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----    -----    -----    -----    ----------------------
 link[2]  |  | -> |f:n| -> |e:n| -> |d:n| -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|
          |  |    -----    -----    -----    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----    ----------------------
 link[3]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|    
          |  |    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----    ----------------------
 link[4]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|     
          |  |    ----------------------
          |  |
          ----
```

Here:

```
    link = (Node **) realloc(link, (N + 1) * sizeof(Node*));
```

the `link` pointer will be reallocated the memory of new size `N + 1` *(assuming `realloc()` was success)*.

and, this loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N + 1; i++){
        link[i] = (Node *)realloc(link[i],(N + 1) * sizeof(Node));
    }
```

will end up reallocating `link[i]` pointer to memory of size `N + 1` objects of `Node` type. You don't need to `realloc()` the `link[i]` pointers. The `link[i]` pointers are head of their respective linked list.

Now, you must be thinking - *why printing of list giving expected output?*
Because the reallocation is done by either:
a) expanding or contracting the existing area pointed to by ptr, if possible. **The contents of the area remain unchanged up to the lesser of the new and old sizes**. If the area is expanded, the contents of the new part of the array are undefined.
b) allocating a new memory block of size new_size bytes, **copying memory area with size equal the lesser of the new and the old sizes**, and freeing the old block.

So, `link[i]` pointers were pointing to a memory of a `Node` type object and `realloc()` will maintain the content of this memory after reallocation.

After reallocation, the in-memory view would be something like this:

```
(read `n` as `next` pointer, x as some garbage value
 and `:` is separator between `data` and `next` member of a node) 

          ----    -------------------------       -----    ----------------------
 link[0]  |  | -> |a:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|   |-> |b:n| -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|
          |  |    ---|---------------------   |   -----    ----------------------
          |  |        \----------------------/
          ----    -------------------------       ----------------------
 link[1]  |  | -> |c:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|   |-> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|
          |  |    ---|---------------------   |   ----------------------
          |  |        \----------------------/
          ----    -------------------------       -----    -----    ----------------------
 link[2]  |  | -> |f:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|   |-> |e:n| -> |d:n| -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|
          |  |    ---|---------------------   |   -----    -----    ----------------------
          |  |        \----------------------/
          ----    --------------------------
 link[3]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|x:n|    
          |  |    --------------------------
          |  |
          ----    --------------------------
 link[4]  |  | -> |-1:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|0:n|x:n|     
          |  |    --------------------------
          |  |
          ----    -------------------------
 link[5]  |  | -> |x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|     
          |  |    -------------------------
          |  |
          ----
```

You can see the `next` pointers are preserved after reallocation and that's why when you are printing the list you are getting output as expected. I hope this giving you clear picture of mistakes you are making while allocating memory.

Now, after this statement

```
    push_front( &link[5], 'c' );
```

the in-memory view of `link[5]` would be something like this:

```
          ----    -----    -------------------------
 link[5]  |  | -> |c|n| -> |x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|x:n|     
          |  |    -----    -------------------------
          |  |
          ----
```

Note that your `output()` may not work as expected while printing the `link[5]` list because the `output()` function `for` loop works on condition `current != NULL && current->data != -1` and neither `realloc()` initialise memory to `0` (as the `calloc()` does) and nor you are assigning `-1` to `list[5]->data`.

You don't need to allocate memory to `link[i]` pointers. The `push_front()` function is allocating the memory and creating a new node and adding that node in the array member list whose address passed as argument to `push_front()` function. Also, you should take care of freeing the list once done with them i.e. free the dynamically allocated memory before exiting.

Putting these altogether:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N   5

typedef struct Node {
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

int push_front (Node **head, char data) {
    Node *new_node = malloc (sizeof (Node));
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if (success) {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void output (Node **head) {
    for (Node *current = *head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        printf ("%c ", current->data);
    }
    printf ("%s", "NULL");
}

void display (Node **set, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("[%d] ", i);
        output (&(set[i]));
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

Node ** reallocate_list (Node **list, size_t old_size, size_t new_size) {
    if (old_size == new_size) {
        return list;
    }

    Node **temp = realloc (list, new_size * sizeof(Node*));
    if (temp == NULL) { 
        printf ("Failed to allocate memory.\n"); 
        /* do cleanup stuff and handle the allocation failure 
         * the way you want. I am simply exiting on allocation failure.
         */
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (old_size < new_size) {
        /* Initialise the newly added elements in the array
         */
        for(size_t i = old_size; i < new_size; i++){
            list[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

void free_list (Node **head) {
    Node *current = *head;
    while (current) {
        Node *x = current->next;
        free (current);
        current = x;
    }
    *head = NULL;
}

void free_all_list (Node **list, size_t num_of_lists) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_of_lists; i++) {
        free_list (&list[i]);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    Node **link;
    link = calloc(N , sizeof (Node*));

    if (link == NULL) {
        printf ("Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("link array size : %d\n", N);

    /* handle the push_front() return value
     */
    push_front (&link[0], 'b');
    push_front (&link[0], 'a');
    push_front (&link[1], 'c');
    push_front (&link[2], 'd');
    push_front (&link[2], 'e');
    push_front (&link[2], 'f');

    display (link, N);

    printf ("Reallocating link array, new size : %d\n", N + 1);
    link = reallocate_list (link, N, N + 1);

    if (link == NULL) {
        printf ("Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    push_front (&link[5], 'c');

    display (link, N + 1);

    free_all_list (link, N + 1);

    free (link);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
link array size : 5
[0] a b NULL
[1] c NULL
[2] f e d NULL
[3] NULL
[4] NULL
Reallocating link array, new size : 6
[0] a b NULL
[1] c NULL
[2] f e d NULL
[3] NULL
[4] NULL
[5] c NULL
```

Comment: Can you recommend me a way to corrent my output function? Thanks for your response